# How to add Oracle data source in jboss 6.2

Tags: oracle, jboss6.x

I searched at many places about this, but I could  not find proper answer. Finally one link helped me, so I am putting it as a question so other so members can utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step by step process can be found here.

http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=872