# How do I install a jdbc driver in JBOSS 6

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I am running JBOSS Enterprise Application Server 6.2.0
I have downloaded the oracle jdbc driver (ojdbc6.jar)

I am looking at the JBOSS documenataion ([JBOSS Admin & Config 6.2.1](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-JDBC_Drivers.html#Install_a_JDBC_Driver_with_the_Management_Console)) but I am confused because there is no step to install the driver. It just points to Section 10.2.2 and says to enable the App.

I am not opposed to installing the driver manually, but I can't tell if section 6.2.2 of the doc is an alternate or a subsequent step.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Turns out this is a duplicate of [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666851/how-to-add-oracle-data-source-in-jboss-6-2) which points to [another thread at middlewaremagic.com](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=872) which explains the process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Oracle data source in jboss 6.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666851/how-to-add-oracle-data-source-in-jboss-6-2)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to copy the JAR file(s) to **JBOSS/Lib**

Check [Where to put a shared library in JBoss AS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108975/where-to-put-a-shared-library-in-jboss-as-5)